# Can a team use GitHub to do version control when some teammates use Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 and some use Visual Studio for Mac?

Tags: visual-studio, github, xamarin.forms

our team plans to use Visual Studio and Xamarin.forms to do hybrid mobile application. Some teammates are using Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 (Windows) and some are using Visual Studio for Mac (Community 2017). Is it possible for us to use Github to do version control? Will there be any conflicts?

Comment: yes, it's possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can both use the same GitHub repo, however there can be adverse effects in terms of formatting. Hence tabs and spacing can be off when you look at it in GitHub, but it will look fine when you are both viewing it in VS for Mac or VS for Windows.

I believe there are also settings to alleviate this issue, but can't remember these off the top of my head.

Comment: Thanks for your reply~ but what do you mean by "tabs and spacing can be off"? So for your advice, it is okay to use VS to code and GitHub to do version control right?

Comment: When you look at it in github, the formatting is all over the place, mainly indentations. This is an issue with file formatting on mac, vs PC. It still merges ok though, and it still looks fine in either VS. Just viewing it on GitHub looks odd in some places. I was told there is a way to align these settings but I don't actually know it. Our team basically just accepts it and continues on anyway.

Comment: The reason you*re seeing such differences is that you have not standardized on the settings related to indentation. You should decide, and configure, once and for all whether to use tabs or spaces, and how big the indentation should be. If you then take the job of fixing formatting in files, there should be no more issues.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, this will work.

We use a hosted git backend with a similar setup.  In our case we use the Visual Studio Team Services git repo, but we use the standard Windows and Mac git clients and I'd expect no difference with github.

Given our devs have come from a Windows and C# background, most of our developers prefer to use Visual Studio on Windows.

We have a shared library that is used by both the Android app and the iOS app.  We tend to do the functionality in the Android app first, but that's only because we prefer Visual Studio and Windows.

When we do *minor* work on the iOS app, that doesn't require layout changes, we can use Visual Studio on *Windows* and remote to the Mac.  This works quite well, the iPhone is plugged into the Mac, but we can debug from Visual Studio.  The lead time between launching to debug and actually debugging this way is a bit slow, but once you're going it really does work.

When we do extensive work on the iOS app, we use Xamarin Studio on the Mac.  This opens the same `.csproj` file that Visual Studio opens. So we could develop the Android app in Xamarin Studio on the Mac if we wanted to.  This is generally a better experience because the Mac is so fast, and particularly, launching the app on the iPhone is much faster if we do it directly on the Mac rather than remotely from VS on Windows.

We use xcode for editing the layout files.  These are `.storyboard` and `.xib` files.  We just open the specific file that we want to edit - xcode doesn't understand `.csproj` files, but Xamarin uses the standard Apple `.storyboard` files for layout.

The only issue we have is with line endings, but it's largely a non-issue.  The git tools tell us on the mac when there are line ending differences.  But none of the IDEs we use appear to be affected.

The line-ending differences seem to come from using XCode for editing the storyboard and other screen layout files.  (We do that because XCode is significantly better at that than the Xamarin Studio or Visual Studio tools).

By standard git tools I mean the following:
On Windows:
- Visual Studio git plugin (which has really good tools for managing merge conflicts)
- Sourcetree from Atlassian
- git command line tools

On Mac:
- Git integration in Xamarin Studio (it does individual file diffs nicely)
- Sourcetree from Atlassian (yep, cross platform)
- git command line tools.

Comment: Do you mean for windows users, they use VS, but for Mac users, they use Xcode? And your team integrate the code very well?